# Java - Adding to an Array using copyOf

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I'm doing an assignment for class which requires me to create an array and add to it as the user wishes. Here's what I have so far:

```
public void add(Scanner stdIn)
{
    entries = new String[1];
    Contact add = new Contact(); // Instantiate new Contact instance

    String name;
    System.out.print("Enter the contact's name: ");
    name = stdIn.next();
    add.setName(name); // set name in Contact class

    String address;
    System.out.print("Enter the contact's address: ");
    address = stdIn.next();
    add.setAddress(address); // set address in Contact class

    String phone;
    System.out.print("Enter the contact's phone number: ");
    phone = stdIn.next();
    add.setPhone(phone); // set phone number in Contact class

    String email;
    System.out.print("Enter the contact's email address: ");
    email = stdIn.next();
    add.setEmail(email); // set email address in Contact class

    final int N = entries.length;

    entries = Arrays.copyOf(entries, N + 1);

    entries[0] = add.toString();

    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(entries));

} // end add
```

I am not too familiar with using arrays, so trying to copy the old array and create a new array with the old information, as well as add new information is alluding me. The toString method looks like this:

```
    @Override // Overrides method from java.lang.Object
    public String toString() // Displays the info for a contact in order
    {
        return getName() + "\t" + getAddress() + "\t" + getPhone() +
                "\t" + getEmail();
    }
```

If you need any more clarification, let me know! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you forced to us an array? Why not use an ArrayLIst? Additionally, you would need to have your array/list defined outside of this method, or else it will go out of scope when the method execution completes and the data lost. Post your entire class as well.

Comment: I think you mean "eluding" and not "alluding".  Don't allude to your problem; please be explicit.  What exactly is not working?  Are you getting error messages?  An exception with a stack trace?  Incorrect output?

Comment: Thanks @pczeus. I am forced to use an array, so your solution was perfect! I see exactly what you mean with the scope of the array, so making those changes to keep the array outside of the add class was a great fix. Now I have to figure out how to remove and update entries :D Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in your comment, you need to define the array (could use an ArrayList instead) outside of the method or it will go out of scope and the data will be lost between calls to the add method.

Here is sample code showing how to make multiple calls to add(), each time expanding the array by 1 and printing the result:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ArrayCopy {
        String[] entries = new String[0];

        public void add(Scanner stdIn)
        {
            entries = Arrays.copyOf(entries, entries.length + 1);

            Contact add = new Contact(); // Instantiate new Contact instance

            String name;
            System.out.print("Enter the contact's name: ");
            name = stdIn.next();
            add.setName(name); // set name in Contact class

            String address;
            System.out.print("Enter the contact's address: ");
            address = stdIn.next();
            add.setAddress(address); // set address in Contact class

            String phone;
            System.out.print("Enter the contact's phone number: ");
            phone = stdIn.next();
            add.setPhone(phone); // set phone number in Contact class

            String email;
            System.out.print("Enter the contact's email address: ");
            email = stdIn.next();
            add.setEmail(email); // set email address in Contact class

            entries[entries.length-1] = add.toString();

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(entries));

        } // end add

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayCopy program = new ArrayCopy();
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String op = "";

            System.out.println("Press A to add a user or E to exit.");
            while(!(op = scan.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("E")){
                switch(op){
                    case "A":
                        program.add(scan);
                        break;
                    case "E":
                        System.out.println("Good Bye.");
                        System.exit(0);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```